# How botmaster use Domain Generating Algorithms (DGA)?

Tags: algorithm, dns, subdomain, domain-name

Domain Generation Algorithms(DGAs) are used in malware to generate a large number of domain names that can be used in communications to the malware’s command and control servers

> For example, an infected computer could create thousands of domain names such as: www.(gibberish).com and would attempt to contact a portion of these with the purpose of receiving an update or commands. - Wikipedia

But my question is we need to buy and register a domain name before we want to use. Then how hacker can generate 10 Thousand of domain name ? and use them ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this.

The malware infects many devices across the globe, and needs to establish communication with the malware controller after infection.
If this address/domain is hardcoded in the malware, it can be easily found and blocked.
For this reason and many others, malware make use of DGA.

DGAs use some sort of seed, for example, today's date.
Using this, and some operations, they come up with a few or thousands of domains in a day.

Now, the hacker/malware author does not have to register all those domains.
The malware will just go on contacting each possible domain to look for commands.
They have to register only one of those millions of possible domains.

When the infected device contacts that domain, the hacker/malware author now has control over that malware, and can now send it commands.

It has been found that authors of Dyre malware had registered some domains 2 years in advance, some authors register domains just a couple of days or even couple of hours before the malware starts making contact.

Bottomline, the malware may generate thousands of queries, but in most cases its only looking for one successful connection, or one registered domain.